# Legends of the Jews sources

Tags: agada-stories-legends

I’ve come across some very interesting midrashim in Legends of the Jews by Louis Ginzberg, but all the versions online I’ve seen of it aren’t sourced. Can anyone find a version online that contains sources for every story (such as footnotes or something)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for volumes 5 & 6 which contain the notes . List of abbreviations of the sources are at the end of the volume.

Volume 5:

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.75591/page/n191/mode/1up

Volume 6:

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.72647/page/n134/mode/1up

Comment: Which exact online version are the footnotes referring to? Are you able to find a link to the first 4 volumes, I wasn’t able to find them on the sight

Comment: https://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/metabook?id=lotj

Comment: Great, thank you!!